# Reference in openpyxl.charts doesn't work (min_col) Python 3

Tags: python, excel, charts, openpyxl

I have simple code from https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/
Which should make a chart, but I have no idea why Reference module doesn't work for me in this example.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.charts import BarChart, Series, Reference

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for i in range(10):
     ws.append([i])

values = Reference(ws, min_col = 1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=10)
chart = BarChart()
chart.add_data(values)
ws.add_chart(chart, "E15")
wb.save("SampleChart.xlsx")
```

It gives me a TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "charts_excel.py", line 9, in <module>
    refObj = openpyxl.charts.Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=10)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_col'
```

Does anyone have an idea why this code doesn't work? I didn't find the answer anywhere. I found couple examples where Reference is used but it also doesn't work for me, for example:

```
values = openpyxl.charts.Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the information in that online book is out of date. Please refer only the official documentation http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/charts/introduction.html which contains the correct import path.

Comment: Thank You, but of course, I checked that in the first place but it still doesn't work. That example code on the website gives exactly the same TypeError.

Comment: Check your version and the imports again. The code in the docs was used to creat the images. You can check this with a checkout and `python doc/charts/bar.py`

Answer (score 0):

It has been quite long since the OP posted the question, but this is likely the issue: probably there is a "Reference" object from another import (not openpyxl) in the global namsespace. I changed the name while importing and the issue was resolved.:

```
from openpyxl.chart import Reference as opyxlReference

...
values = opyxlReference(ws, min_col = 1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=10)
```